# xlsxwriter OUTPUT formatting

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a if else statement. What I'm trying to do is.

I'm looping through and seeing if there's a specific text on something if it does;
add that text in my output in a specific column if it doesn't leave that field null. However it seems to leave all the field null.

This is my code

```
for items in parseBio1:

        if "Snapchat" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row+1,col+13,items)
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+13,"None")

        if "com" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row+1, col+11, items)
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+11,"None")
```

This is the output I get.

[image]

Per requested. Here's the way I'm parsing my input

```
parseBio1 = parseBio.split('\n')
    row+=1

    for items in parseBio1:

        if "Snapchat" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row+1,col+13,items)
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+13,"None")
```

This is what happens when i get rid of else statement like this:

```
for items in parseBio1:

        digit = items.isdigit()


        if "Snapchat" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row+1,col+13,items)

        if "com" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row+1, col+11, items)
```

The output looks messed up and isn't located where it is suppose to be.
In this case. Row 0 item 'snapchat' field is in row 1 for a different user like this
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample input, and the code you use to parse the input?

Comment: Obviously your `else` statements are working. That must mean your `if` statements don't trigger. `Items` is a list here. When you type `if "Snapchat" in list` it is looking for an item in your list that matches `"Snapchat"` exactly. If there is some other junk in the item (like a space), it will not match.

Comment: @TammoHeeren My question was. How do I set that row/column to NULL if the if statements don't trigger.

Comment: @dbcs Added at the bottom of the thread!

Comment: so are the contents of items a list of strings like @TammoHeeren said, or are they just a string?

Comment: Instead of adding `"None"`, have you tried `None` or not even adding a string at all? Just skip the `else`.

Comment: @TammoHeeren Yes. I've tried adding "pass" in my if else statement. It seem to mess up my output.

Comment: @TammoHeeren I'll update the thread/script with what happens when i get rid of else statement

Comment: You need to increment row by 2, not just by 1. In you if statements you either write to row+1 or row. And you are writing a list (`items`) to a single cell. That may also not work well. If `items` is indeed a list (my guess).

Comment: Adding row+2 just pushed my "none" value down. It seems more messed up now. 

So I tested doing if "Snapchat" in items:
It printed me one snapchat from one array just the way I wanted it. I am just stuck in a syntax issue.

Comment: I'm just trying to do. Loop through my list. If "Snapchat" is found in my list. Simply append it to my csv file in the right row/column

Comment: I guess I don't understand why one result of the if statement is put into `row` while the other is put into `row+1`.

Comment: @TammoHeeren I added row+1 so it doesn't replace my values. I'll send add the entire worksheet fields in the thread. So you can understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
for items in parseBio1:

        if "Snapchat" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col+13, items)
        if "com" in items:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col+11, items)

        row += 1
```

In this way if either `Snapchat` or `com` in items, it will populate the respective columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you are iterating through a list of strings that were delimited by '\n'. If so your conditions for your if statements may be slightly inaccurate. You might be trying to look for words written in different cases, which python does not account for:

```
>> x = "Testing the waters"
>> "test" in x
False
```

Therefore, I recommend you calling .lower() on items in your conditionals, and comparing them to an all-lowercase word.

```
for items in parseBio1:

    # Try to call .lower() on items and compare to an all lowercase string
    if "snapchat" in items.lower():
        worksheet.write_string(row+1,col+13,items)
    else:
        worksheet.write_string(row,col+13,"None")

    if "com" in items.lower():
        worksheet.write_string(row+1, col+11, items)
    else:
        worksheet.write_string(row,col+11,"None")
```

Comment: No. I've actually tested my input. My parsing is done the way I want it to be. I want python to look for "Snapchat" word and not "snapchat". If it returns me false; simply set that row/column value to NULL. That's all I really want to do.

Comment: I got the parsing handled and is done the way I want. I've checked it multiple times.